# How to add privleges/roles to Clearance gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, rubygems, clearance

I have the basic clearance setup -

```
rails generate clearance:install
```

and

```
rails generate clearance:views
```

In my admin_controller, I have

```
before_filter :authorize
```

This makes sure the user is logged in. How would I setup 'admin' privileges on my users and make sure the user has the privlege before allowing them into the admin controller?

Is there a better solution for this?

Thanks!

Andrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mix it with CanCan

https://github.com/ryanb/cancan

http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan

Comment: As mentioned, cancan is your friend here. Follow [this](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Role-Based-Authorization) tutorial to sort it out.

Answer (score 6):

i had the same question, but `cancan` seems too much for me (small project)

Actually the [source code](https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance/blob/cbe47c03effbe93f5cd9a6be05ea9b84c274a851/lib/clearance/authorization.rb#L9-13) of `authorize` is quite simple, so my approach here:

open the `Clearance::Authorization` module in initializer, and add custom methods there:

```
# config/initializers/clearance_authorization.rb

module Clearance
  module Authorization
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    def authorize_admin
      unless(signed_in? && current_user.admin?)
        deny_access
      end
    end
  end
end
```

don't forget to restart the server :)